# Where is the Sculpt Brush radius lock in 2.8?

Tags: sculpting

I've been trying to find the radius lock in 2.8 and i just can't find it anywhere

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ehS.png[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this feature changed the name to be more intuitive: It's now on Options menu, the name is "Radius Unit" and can be modified to "View" and "Scene". You can see this options on the right/down corner of your picture.

Comment: Are you kidding me?! It was right in front of my face... THANKS!